# Temporarily Disabling the Main Font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, times, default, timesfont

In the following MWE, I have defined `cabin` as the default font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[12]
\vspace{10pt}

% I would like to use the default font for this paragraph.
\lipsum[3]
\vspace{10pt}

% I would now like to restore the default font (cabin).
\lipsum[13]
\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

How may I disable the main font in order to print the second paragraph *only* with the default font?

Does anyone know what the default font is? If it is not Times New Roman, how may I specify Times New Roman for the second paragraph only?

Comment: which engine do you use for compilation?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am using `pdflatex`

Comment: then you get the default font with {\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont xxx}

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would I replace the `xxx` by `Times`? by `Times New Roman`?

Comment: xxx means some text. If you want to use a font looking like times, you could try `{\fontfamily{qtm}\selectfont some text}`.

Comment: Thank you @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what would be the reason. Anyway, with pdflatex you need to know that you get Times (not Times New Roman, I'm afraid) or a clone thereof by its family name and you can choose among a few ones.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[12]

\vspace{10pt}

% I would like to use the default font for this paragraph.
{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont % the legacy clone
\lipsum[3][1-4]}

\vspace{10pt}

% I would like to use the default font for this paragraph.
{\fontfamily{qtm}\selectfont % TeX Gyre
\lipsum[3][1-4]}

\vspace{10pt}

% I would like to use the default font for this paragraph.
{\fontfamily{ntxtlf}\selectfont % NewTX
\lipsum[3][1-4]}

\vspace{10pt}

% I would now like to restore the default font (cabin).
\lipsum[13]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you want to define an environment for the job.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin} 
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{usetimes}{% use ptm, qtm, ntxtlf or other
  \par\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}{\par}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[12]

\vspace{10pt}

\begin{usetimes}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\end{usetimes}

\vspace{10pt}

% I would now like to restore the default font (cabin).
\lipsum[13]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default font is Computer Modern. If you want to use Times New Roman you have to switch from the compiler pdfLaTeX to LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX. About fonts there is a lot of documentation. If you want to go deeper start searching about open type and type 1 fonts and then go on. To make it simple use LuaLaTex or XeLaTeX as compiler and change the preamble as shown below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec} %for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX if you use an open type font
\usepackage{polyglossia}%it is like babel but for LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX

\usepackage{cabin} 

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[12] %default is computer modern
\vspace{10pt}

%usually for famous fonts you can use just their name if they are already installed in your pc
{\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\lipsum[3]
}
\vspace{10pt}

{\setmainfont{Arial}
\lipsum[13]
}
\vspace{10pt}

%you can also specify fon by \usefont{<encoding>}{<family>}{<series>}{<shape>}
{\usefont{T1}{qpl}{m}{sc}
\lipsum[15]
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated but you can use babel with xelatex and lualatex too without problems.

Comment: Can a switch to Times New Roman be made with `pdflatex`?

Comment: No, because is an open type font and it can not be compiled with pdflatex. You can looking for a very similar font to use if you want to use pdflatex, but i don't have any examples. Now It comes to my mind only a less practical way: you could use times new roman like font as the main font with \usepackage{mathptmx} and then switch to whatever you want in the way I showed before.

Comment: This is a command for a very similar one with pdfLaTeX:{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont Some text}